# Alocação dinâmica

Tags: c, array, alocação

Estou tentando modificar o vetor com os valores inseridos pelo usuário de modo que o menor elemento fique no início e maior fique no final (e o resto do vetor fique inalterado). Porém, estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro quando o usuário (eu) termina de digitar o vetor. Como contornar isso?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void maxmin(int* V, int tamanho, int* max, int* min)
{
int i;
i = 0;

*max = *(V+i);
*min = *(V + i);

for (i = 1; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    if (*(V + i) > *max)
    {
        *max = *(V + i);
    }
    else if (*(V + i) < *min)
    {
        *min = *(V + i);
    }
}
return;
}

void printIntArray(int* V, int tamanho)
{
int i,elemento;
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    elemento = *(V + i);
    printf(" %d ", elemento);
}
printf("\n");
return;
}

void CriarVetor(int* V, int tamanho)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    printf("Inserir elemento da posicao %d:", i);
    scanf("%d", V + i);
}
printf("Vetor:\n");
printIntArray(V, tamanho);
return;
}
int Posicao(int* v, int tamanho, int elemento)
{
int i,pos;

for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    if (*(v + i) == elemento)
    {
        pos = *(v + i);
        return pos;
    }
}
return NULL;
}
int *sort(int* v, int tamanho,int *v_ord)
{
int i,min,max,pos_min,pos_max;

maxmin(v, tamanho, &max, &min);
pos_min= Posicao(v, tamanho,min);
pos_max = Posicao(v, tamanho, max);
*(v_ord+0) = min;
free(v + pos_min);
free(v + pos_max);
for (i = 1; i < tamanho-1; i++)
{
    *(v_ord + i) = *(v + i - 1);
    if (v == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
*(v_ord + tamanho-1) = max;

return v_ord;
}
int main(void)
{
int *Vetor_de_inteiros,*Vetor_ordenado;
int tamanho,max, min;

printf("Inserir quantidade de elementos:");
scanf("%d", &tamanho);

Vetor_de_inteiros= (int*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));
CriarVetor(Vetor_de_inteiros, tamanho);

Vetor_ordenado= (int*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));

Vetor_ordenado=sort(Vetor_de_inteiros, tamanho, Vetor_ordenado);

if (Vetor_ordenado == NULL)
{
    printf("Memoria insuficiente\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Vetor ordenado:\n");
printIntArray(Vetor_ordenado, tamanho);

free(Vetor_de_inteiros);
free(Vetor_ordenado);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que estás a tentar fazer com esses dois ```free(v + pos_min);``` ```free(v + pos_max);``` na função sort?

Comment: O free seria para eliminar estes elementos do vetor

Comment: Estás a fazer isso de forma errada, o teu programa "rebenta" nessas linhas. Caso queiras alterar o tamanho de um vetor dinâmico sugiro que veja a função ```void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size)```. Pelo que percebi do exercício basta apenas encontrar o menor e o maior elemento do vetor e posicionar na primeira e ultima posição respetivamente reorganizado o resto das posições, isto implica manter o tamanho do vetor. Sugiro que começes por comentar esses dois ```free();``` e que encontres uma solução de reorganizar o vetor para preencher a vaga deixada tanto pelo menor quanto pelo maior valor.

Comment: Se o que você quer em `sort()` é colocar o menor no início e o maior no fim está seguindo um caminho incrivelmente complicado. E tem os erros. Não sei se é melhor corrigir os erros ou mudar o caminho. É isso mesmo que quer fazer? `sort()` é nesse caso colocar o menor no início e o maior no fim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    int i;
    i = 0;
    *max = *(V + i);
    *min = *(V + i);
```

Que pretende com essas linhas? Se acabou de escrever `i = 0` não está claro que `V+i` é a mesma coisa que `V`?

Porque não inicializa `i` na mesma linha em que declarou, a linha de cima?

Considere que poderia ter escrito apenas

```
void        maxmin(int* V, int tamanho, int* max, int* min)
{   // retorna a posicao do menor e maior valor do vetor
    *max = *min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < tamanho; i++)
        if (*(V + i) > *(V+ *max))
            *max = i;  // novo max
        else if (*(V + i) < *(V+ *min))
            *min = i;  // novo min
    return;
}
```

Retornando as posições dos valores e não os valores. Do modo como escreveu precisa depois chamar outra função `Posicao()` e procurar de novo a mesma coisa, e vai perder muito tempo.

#### printIntArray()

```
void printIntArray(int* V, int tamanho)
{
    int i, elemento;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
    {
        elemento = *(V + i);
        printf(" %d ", elemento);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
```

Essa nomenclatura é mais comum em java. Em C o provável é `print_int_array()`

- De todo modo como tem uma função para isso e óbvios dois usos no mínimo, mostrar o vetor antes e depois do `"sort"` considere usar um título opcional. Veja no exemplo que vou deixar ao final.
- não precisa de `elemento`
- declare a variável de controle do loop no loop. Levou muitos anos para arrumarem isso na linguagem, mas já faz 40 anos.
- talvez seja boa idéia controlar o número de colunas
- evite usar espaços antes e depois de um elemento. Só dificulta o controle. Não use `" %d "`. Use `"%d  "` ou `"  %d"`

Exemplo:

```
void printIntArray(int* V, int tamanho, const char* msg)
{
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    for (int i = 0, col = 0; i < tamanho; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%6d", *(V + i));
        if ( ++col % 5 == 0 ) printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}
```

#### CriarVetor()

Se tem `printIntArray()` porque não `createVector()`? Talvez possa usar uma nomenclatura mais linear.

- Ao ler o vetor podia ir repetindo o total, por cortesia.
- TESTE **sempre** o retorno de `scanf()`. Se não ler o segundo de 10 ítens vai deixar a leitura seguir? Qual será o valor para o item que não leu?
- Talvez não deva chamar `printIntArray()` de dentro de `CriarVetor()`. Mantenha a função simples e genérica. Apenas crie o vetor. Ao chamar `CriarVetor()` o programa resolve se vai chamar também `printfIntArray()`. Mais flexível.
- Se `sort()` retorna um `int*` com o vetor "ordenado" porque criarVetor()` não retorna um ponteiro para o vetor lido? Use uma lógica uniforme.
- Considere retornar o ponteiro para o vetor criado. É o normal em C.

#### int Posicao(int* v, int tamanho, int elemento)

Use uma convenção uniforme para os nomes das funções: idioma, inicial maiúscula...

```
int Posicao(int* v, int tamanho, int elemento)
{
    int i, pos;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
    {
        if (*(v + i) == elemento)
        {
            pos = *(v + i);
            return pos;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Não pode retornar `NULL`. É o mesmo que zero então como vai diferenciar se o elemento não existe ou se é o primeiro, cujo índice é... `0`?

- declare `i` dentro do `for`
- não precisa de `pos`
- e afinal não precisa dessa função. Está errado: basta retornar os índices e não os valores de `maxmin()`

Prefira

```
int posicao(int* v, int tamanho, int elemento)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
        if (*(v + i) == elemento)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

retornando o índice ou `-1`

#### `sort()`

```
int* sort(int* v, int tamanho, int* v_ord)
{
    int i, min, max, pos_min, pos_max;

    maxmin(v, tamanho, &max, &min);
    pos_min      = Posicao(v, tamanho, min);
    pos_max      = Posicao(v, tamanho, max);
    *(v_ord + 0) = min;
    free(v + pos_min);
    free(v + pos_max);
    for (i = 1; i < tamanho - 1; i++)
    {
        *(v_ord + i) = *(v + i - 1);
        if (v == NULL) { return NULL; }
    }
    *(v_ord + tamanho - 1) = max;

    return v_ord;
}
```

Supondo que `sort()` vá criar e retornar o vetor "ordenado", já que retorna `int*`, ainda fica a dúvida: o que é o tal `v_ord`? Não faz sentido.

E o que são essas chamadas a `free()`? O argumento para `free` deve ser algo que veio de `malloc()`. Imagina estar removendo algo do meio do vetor? Não funciona. E de todo modo a saída é outro vetor, e imagino que seja esse `v_ord`.
Essa parte está bem errada.
E aqui pode ver como é muito mais simples retornar as posições do maior e do menor valor, ao invés de retornar o valor e depois ter que ir de novo no vetor procurar a posição que você já tinha achado...

Compare:

```
int* sort(int* v, int tamanho)
{   // retorna o vetor com o menor no inicio
    // e o maior no fim
    int min;
    int max;
    maxmin(v, tamanho, &max, &min);
    int* v_ord = (int*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));  // cria o novo
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
        *(v_ord + i) = *(v + i); // copia tudo
    int um                 = *(v_ord);  // salva o primeiro
    *(v_ord)               = *(v_ord + min);
    *(v_ord + min)         = um;                      // inverte
    um                     = *(v_ord + tamanho - 1);  // o ultimo
    *(v_ord + tamanho - 1) = *(v_ord + max);
    *(v_ord + max)         = um;  // inverte
    return v_ord;
}
```

A lógica de `maxmin()` poderia muito bem estr incluída em `sort()`

#### `main()`

Considerando o que escrevi sobre as rotinas, veja uma implementação comum para `main()`

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(210925);
    int  tamanho = 0;
    printf("Inserir quantidade de elementos:");
    if ( 1 != scanf("%d", &tamanho)) return -1;

    // le e mostra original
    printf("Lendo vetor de %d elementos\n", tamanho);
    int* Vetor_de_inteiros = criarVetor(tamanho);
    printIntArray(Vetor_de_inteiros, tamanho, "\n    Vetor Original\n");

    // ordena e mostra
    int* Vetor_ordenado = sort(Vetor_de_inteiros, tamanho);
    printIntArray(Vetor_ordenado, tamanho, "\n    Vetor Ordenado\n");

    // apaga tudo
    free(Vetor_de_inteiros);
    free(Vetor_ordenado);
    return 0;
}
```

Essa é a maneira comum de escrever isso. Usei uma versão de `criarVetor()` que devolve um vetor preenchido com números no intervalo [-500,500] só para poder testar sem perder tempo digitando.

#### saída do exemplo para 19 números

```
Inserir quantidade de elementos:19
Lendo vetor de 19 elementos

    Vetor Original

   202   -40  -245  -461   361
  -186   454   -25    16  -253
   376    15   383   218  -160
   346  -375  -243  -153

    Vetor Ordenado

  -461   -40  -245   202   361
  -186  -153   -25    16  -253
   376    15   383   218  -160
   346  -375  -243   454
```

#### O código completo

```
/*
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/528981/aloca%c3%a7%c3%a3o-din%c3%a2mica
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int*        criarVetor(int);
void        maxmin(int*, int, int*, int*);
int         posicao(int*, int, int);
void        printIntArray(int*, int, const char*);
int*        sort(int*,int);

int main(void)
{
    srand(210925);
    int  tamanho = 0;
    printf("Inserir quantidade de elementos:");
    if ( 1 != scanf("%d", &tamanho)) return -1;

    // le e mostra original
    printf("Lendo vetor de %d elementos\n", tamanho);
    int* Vetor_de_inteiros = criarVetor(tamanho);
    printIntArray(Vetor_de_inteiros, tamanho, "\n    Vetor Original\n");

    // ordena e mostra
    int* Vetor_ordenado = sort(Vetor_de_inteiros, tamanho);
    printIntArray(Vetor_ordenado, tamanho, "\n    Vetor Ordenado\n");

    // apaga tudo
    free(Vetor_de_inteiros);
    free(Vetor_ordenado);
    return 0;
}

int*        criarVetor(int tamanho)
{   // retorna o endereco do novo vetor
    int* V = (int*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));
    // usa um numero entre -500 e +500
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
        *(V + i) = -500 + rand() % 1001;
    return V;
}

void        maxmin(int* V, int tamanho, int* max, int* min)
{   // retorna a posicao do menor e maior valor do vetor
    *max = *min = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < tamanho; i++)
        if (*(V + i) > *(V+ *max))
            *max = i;  // novo max
        else if (*(V + i) < *(V+ *min))
            *min = i;  // novo min
    return;
}

int         posicao(int* v, int tamanho, int elemento) 
{   // retorna a posicao do primeiro com esse valor
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
        if (*(v + i) == elemento) return i;
    return -1;
}

void        printIntArray(int* V, int tamanho, const char* msg)
{   // mostra o vetor, com um titulo
    if (msg != NULL) printf("%s\n", msg);
    for (int i = 0, col = 0; i < tamanho; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%6d", *(V + i));
        if ((++col)%5 == 0) printf("\n"); // 5 por linha
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int* sort(int* v, int tamanho)
{   // retorna o vetor com o menor no inicio
    // e o maior no fim
    int min;
    int max;
    maxmin(v, tamanho, &max, &min);
    int* v_ord = (int*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));  // cria o novo
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
        *(v_ord + i) = *(v + i); // copia tudo
    int um                 = *(v_ord);  // salva o primeiro
    *(v_ord)               = *(v_ord + min);
    *(v_ord + min)         = um;                      // inverte
    um                     = *(v_ord + tamanho - 1);  // o ultimo
    *(v_ord + tamanho - 1) = *(v_ord + max);
    *(v_ord + max)         = um;  // inverte
    return v_ord;
}
```

Talvez ache mais simples escrever assim. É o comum em C.